# Load Vue Components from Server at a specific time

Tags: vue.js, asynchronous, electron, vite, server-side-rendering

I have an electron app made with vue and electron-vite. In order to protect the components, I want to only have them on the server and have the app request them at a certain time.

At first I thought I could accomplish this with SSR as detailed [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/ssr.html#basic-tutorial) but it looks like SSR requires the component to be defined on both the client and the server.

I also stumbled upon async components [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/async.html), but again, it seems like the components need to be already on the client for them to work.

The ideal situation would be, once the electron app authenticates, it'll request basically the entire UI from the server once. The UI will be rendered server side so only html and js is sent to the client. The client app would only have to do this once, as vue hydration would make everything reactive and enable the app to then be used offline.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are they supposed to look like when you request them? Possibly this https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/components#standalone-server-components and https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/nuxt-island

Comment: @EstusFlask that does look promising. One possible issue is it looks like `ServerComponents` well re send a request to re fetch every time their props are updated. Do you know if this includes nested components as well? Say I have an `App` component with many children, if one of those children's props update, will the whole `App` be re fetched from the server?

Comment: Which of them is a server component? I didn't use it it practice, notice that it's experimental and can behave in undocumented ways

Comment: @EstusFlask the first link you referenced would be the Server Components. The second link, `<NuxtIsland>` doesn't look like it'll work as its for non interactive components. I also updated my question to be a bit more specific with what I want to do.

Comment: No, I don't see any form of server rendering to be particularly useful here. Server-only comps would make sense for the ones that are inefficient or sensitive to be rendered on client side, but the whole app cannot be 'sensitive'. You can make it regular Vue app and authenticate the requests for assets, but I don't see a good reason for this. Anything that happens in a browser, even electron, can be relatively easily tampered

Comment: @EstusFlask I don't mind if things are tampered with, that I know I can't completely prevent. What I'm aiming for is, if the app is cracked, tampered, redistributed, etc. that anyone using the tampered version won't be able to really 'use' it since the main UI needs to be loaded from my server after proper authentication, if that makes sense

Comment: The app can be slightly modified to load UI from cached files instead of network, and cache contents can be relatively easily intercepted and stored. I don't think it's specific to electron, at this point it doesn't look any different than just loading the app from remote url like regular website. As long as a website doesn't use some restricted api calls, you can't prevent a user from saving the whole website locally and running it, there are a few gotchas that need some expertise but it's doable

Comment: @EstusFlask Can you elaborate on `As long as a website doesn't use some restricted api calls, you can't prevent a user from saving the whole website locally and running it`. Are you saying you can prevent users from saving things locally?

Comment: No, I mean that there's no way how client-side code could be safe in terms of stealing, electron or not, but a way to make it unusable for cracking is to rely on authenticated backend calls, so it couldn't efficiently work offline, which is not the case here

Comment: @EstusFlask that's what I thought. Thanks for talking it through with me. I think I know what to do to now to make it as secure as possible.